# java lucene class not found problem

Tags: java, lucene, classpath

I keep getting this error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex

Is there any way i can go about making sure java/tomcat can find this class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This class does not exist in the core lucene jar you are using but in a contrib jar called lucene-memory-2.4.1.jar. Make sure you include this jar in your application as well.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, this solved the issue, loaded it to the common lib for tomcat, and now lucene correctly highlights phrases.. THANKS